# Is it possible to edit a sql query using a query itself

Tags: sql-server

I have a sample query to insert data into the table.However, a table name has been misspelled. The same mistake is continued for about 120 records. Is there any query that can be written so that I can correct it in one record and apply the changes to the rest automatically? or do I have to do it manually?

Comment: Is it as simple as ```UPDATE myTable SET columnName = rightTableName WHERE columnName = wrongTableName```?

Comment: @Matty I do not want to change the column names of the table. I just want to correct a misspelled column name in the query and apply that changes to all the other queries

Comment: When you say "record", what do you *actually* mean (because you certainly don't mean record)?  Do you mean script, stored procedure, view, UDF, etc.?  The solution will depend on how these queries are stored, e.g. if they are all scripts then you could use an external find and replace tool, for a stored procedure you would have more difficulty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it possible in SSDT Project.

1. create SSDT Project
2. import your database
3. right click column in script and choose Refactor->Rename

Comment: I have a sample script provided by my uni. In there, the customer_Id has been typed in as just Id. I cannot use that because it's going to be a problem when linking with other tables. So I want to change Id into CustomerId in each an every insert query given in the script. I tried using SSDT but it says "please select a valid symbol" how do you change Id to customerId? It works with other columns in the customer table. But not with this one.(This is the primary key)

Comment: I have no problems with renaming PK. Have you any build errors?  "I cannot use that because it's going to be a problem when linking with other tables" - what do you mean? Please post code that have problems. Renaming do not solve any problems, it's for beauty only.

Comment: INSERT INTO [Customer] ([Id],[FirstName],[LastName],[City],[Country],[Phone])VALUES(55,'R...','Phillips','Anchorage','USA','(907) 555-4')
GO

Comment: Is `[Id]` column identity? By default you cannot insert values in identity columns (it can be changed by IDENTITY_INSERT)